# running a stress test by jmeter for web services with nested procedures

Tags: web-services, jmeter-5.0, stress-testing

Dears,
I'm trying to stress test our .net web service using jMeter, I want to get its response time, and check how many requests the service can response, but this application when it receives a request it calls a procedure in another server to get the result of that request, How do I know which server is responsible for the low performance? , Is it the server hosting the application, or is it the other server? Also, how to detect a bottleneck, and is there any risk that our request may stop after a certain number of requests.

Regards

I expect to get a detailed graph showing important and understandable information